# Can I get my HTML List to ignore External CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

just a quick question.

I have some external CSS that I don't want to change... it's looking like I might have to. See below.

```
li { line-height: 18px; margin-bottom: 12px; }
```

I want to add a one-off list with no line-height or margin... Is there a way I can get this list to completley ignore the CSS? I've tried the !important rule below, but this doesn't overwrite it.

```
.plist {
    list-style-type:disc;
    padding:0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    line-height: 0 !important;

}

<ul class="plist">
        <li>All new OE Castings</li>
        <li>Enlarged intake and exhaust ports</li>
        <li>Large diameter stainless steel intake valves</li>
        <li>Large diameter inconel exhaust valves</li>
        <li>Hi-rev, dual valve springs</li>
        <li>Titanium retainers</li>
        <li>Hardened steel spring platforms</li>

    </ul>
```

Any ways round this? Would you just recommend being more precise with my CSS?

Comment: Did you try using  ".plist li" to overwrite ?

Comment: is `.plist` the class of your `li` or `ul` / `ol`?  please provide your html for the list

Comment: added my HTML Pete ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `!important`.

The best thing is to create a new class for that list, if you can't, use more specificity with selectors to get the result you want.

E.g.

```
.plist li {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help you in this case but using `inherit` on the css attributes should work.

E.g. :

```
.plist li#specialList {
    margin: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use important in this code

//try this code

.plist {

```
list-style-type:disc;

padding:0px;

margin:0px;


line-height:0px ;
```

}